# Sorting by time not working truly in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I think title is clear what is my problem. I am working with MySql I just wanted to know what was the first registration on my website and when I sorted the table according to **timestamp**, the **id** of people who registered on the website were not true. The Image bellow will show what do I mean:
[image: phpMyAdmin]

and this is the code what phpMyAdmin created:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
ORDER BY `table`.`timestamp` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

whats wrong with my table time? and why **id** is not ordered same as **timestamps**

Comment: What updates timestamp? is id an AUTO_INCREMENT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that `id` is an auto-increment field, then this is almost certainly due to the fact that `timestamp` column is not assigned at the same physical time the `id` column is assigned. For example, if you have a multi-page registration from a website application, the initial object may be inserted into the database to contain the initial data fields gathered on the first page. But perhaps the `timestamp` is only set after the final page of registration is complete. So depending on the time the user takes to complete registration, the `timestamp` can be out-of-sync with the `id` order.

There are multiple ways to work around this. One way is to assign `timestamp` when the record is first inserted into the database, or you could use a DB insert trigger to populate the `timestamp` field instead.

There is also the possibility that `timestamp` represents the date and time the user last modified their profile (or otherwise caused modification of the database record). In this case, the `timestamp` could be changing to a "future" value while the `id` stays constant.